How can I reorganize this sql data using either a better query statement or Pandas from Python?
How can I go about changing my current table/excel file to something that is grouped by school (row) and organized by month (column) and the cycle in the appropriate rowXcolumn cell? Would I have to change my query or can something in python be used, like pandas?
Current excel file:



School
Code
Zone
Month
Cycle




Mountain
574
1.2
1
420000


Mountain
574
1.2
2
600000


Terrace
574
1.3
4
660000


Hill
574
1.4
4
900000


Hill
574
1.4
5
420000


Abel
574
1.4
6
480000



Desired excel file:



School
Code
Jan
Feb
Mar




Mountain
574
420000
600000
0


Terrace
574
600000
660000
600000


Hill
574
420000
0
660000


Abel
574
480000
900000
900000



I know the example data doesn't line up but how would I go about getting this format?
I tried using case when statements, different group bys, and some panda functions to manipulate the data but nothing seemed to quite work.

Use a pivot table in Excel, or pivot the data in your query or in pandas.

Please explain how your desired is derived from your current files. The values in desired don't seem to match up with the months in current for many of your examples

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

import calendar; out = df.pivot(index='School', columns='Month', values='Cycle').fillna(0); out.columns=pd.Series(out.columns).apply(lambda m:calendar.month_abbr[m])
